# NSCharacterSet cuts the string

Tags: objective-c, nscharacterset

I am getting lastest tweet and show it in my app. I put it in a NSMutableString and initialize that string like below in my xmlparser.m file:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

I can get the tweet but somehow it cuts some of the tweets and shows some part of it. For example tweet is

> Video games in the classroom? Social media & #technology can change education http://bit.ly/KfGViF @GOVERNING #edtech

but what it shows is:

> #technology can change education http://bit.ly/KfGViF @GOVERNING #edtech

Why do you think it is? I tried to initialize currentNodeContent in other ways to but I could not solve the problem.

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Is the string variable being passed into the method exactly what you expect it to be?

Comment: I don't know what's causing the trimming problem, but that is not the way you get a mutable string. You need to call `mutableCopy` on the trimmed string instance. You can't just cast.

Answer (score 1):

Event-driven (SAX) parsers are free to return only part of the text of a node in a callback. You might only be getting part of the tweet passed in. You should probably accumulate characters in a mutable string until you get a callback indicating the end of the element. See Listing 3 and the surrounding text in [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html).

Comment: In particular, the above code snippet is probably being called repeatedly with segments of the tweet (probably three times with: the part before the entity for the ampersand ('&'), the ampersand entity itself, and the part after the ampersand).  It's overwriting the `currentNodeContent` each time and thus only remembering the last part.

Comment: I tried to do something like currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
     [currentStringValue appendString:string]; but this time I get SIGBRT error saying that 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'

Answer (score 0):

You've got two problems here:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

Simply casting an `NSString` to an `NSMutableString` doesn't work. You have to make a mutable copy yourself or initialise a new `NSMutableString` using the contents of an `NSString`.

Furthermore, the text parser is only giving you the last part of the string because it may be interpreting the '`&`' simply as part of an entity reference, or it may be an entity reference itself.

What you probably want to do is:

1. Before you begin parsing, initialise `currentNodeContent` so that it is an empty `NSMutableString`:

   ```
   currentNodeContent = [NSMutableString string];
   ```
2. As you are parsing, *append* the characters to the `currentNodeContent`:

   ```
   [currentNodeContent appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
   ```

Comment: This time I get [NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0' error

Comment: @user1244069: Try `currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];` instead. But also post the code where you are trying to insert an object into an array.

Comment: This is where I initialized it:-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];}